# LineRenderer and move

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я рисую линию то объект летел по ней?

Comment: `LineRenderer` содержит массив координат `Vector3`. Вам остается лишь взять их и перемещать объект по этим точкам.

Comment: Я вот пытался сделать подобное, но у меня не вышло. Если не сложно, можете написать код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3[] positions;
    public LineRenderer line;
    public GameObject item;
    int step;
    float speed = 10f;

    void Start() {
        if(line.positionCount > 0) {
            positions = new Vector3[line.positionCount];
            line.GetPositions(positions);
            item.transform.position = positions[0];
            StartCoroutine(run());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator run() {
        while(step < positions.Length) {
            item.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(item.transform.position, positions[step], Time.deltaTime * speed);
            if(Vector3.Distance(item.transform.position, positions[step]) < 0.2f) {
                step++;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]